# Cant take the Set-Cookie Header in Client

Tags: express, cookies, header, client, token

Set-Cookie, Client, Express, Javascript

I am sending the cookie to the respone with this

```
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
  res.cookie('token', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneDay),
    secure: 'production',
    signed: true,
  })

  return token
```

I can see the cookie if I log it on server and also in the client on the headers.

my client code

```
const pass = document.querySelector('#password')
const email = document.querySelector('#email')
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const btn2 = document.querySelector('#btn2')
btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
const pass = document.querySelector('#password')
const email = document.querySelector('#email')
axios
.post('http://localhost:4550/api/v1/auth/login', {
email: email.value,
password: pass.value,
}).then((response) => {
console.log(response.headers['set-cookie'])
}).catch((err) => console.log(err))
})
```

on click I am getting 2 responses one 200 and 204 the 200 is ok because I created, any way I think that's the reason that I'm getting the Set-Cookie from the headers, the value is undified how can I fix this? To take the token and stop sending 2 requests instead of 1.